# warning: Insecure world writable dir .../osx/bin in PATH, mode 040777 with Homebrew

Tags: ruby, installation, homebrew

I'm using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for compiling/installing Mac command line tools. It uses ruby for implementation, and whenever I user `homebrew install SOMETHING`, I got `warning: Insecure world writable dir .../osx/bin in PATH, mode 040777` warnings. The bin directory has permission of 777. Why is this warnings, and how do I remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to have a `777` directory in your path because other users can put executables in there and trick you into running them with your privileges. To fix, just change it to `755` or `775`. (Of course, if you're the only user of your computer, you have nothing to worry about.)